# what will be the Execution Time of Coded UI when compared with QTP

Tags: coded-ui-tests, qtp, codedom

I have 300 Test Cases automated in QTP, while after execution it takes almost 430 minutes. If I execute those test cases in CODED UI, will it take more than 430 minutes or less than 430 minutes. Please reply and let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Easy! Use the period-finding subroutine to find r, the period of the following function:
f(x)=a^{x} mod {N}, f(x)=a^{x} mod {N},
i.e. the order r of a in ({Z} _{N})^{\times}, which is the smallest positive integer r for which f(x+r)=f(x)} f(x+r)=f(x), or f(x+r)=a^{x+r}{N} a^{x} mod {N}. f(x+r)=a^{x+r} {N} a^{x} {N}}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the tests, this is impossible to answer.

The best way to discover for yourself is to take a sample QTP test (perhaps your longest-running), rewrite it using Coded UI, and see what the difference between the 2 run times is.